# Why Didn't the Immortal Take the Shirt?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-protector

In the Netflix series "The Protector", when the Immortal killed Hakan's parents, why didn't he take the shirt?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I mean it seems vague for people who don't know the show.